# I am expecting my boolean to be saved in shared preferences as true, however it always saves as false

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to save a boolean into shared preferences with a value of true but when I log it I keeping seeing it returning a false value. Please see the code below and also bear in mind that this code is within a fragment.

```
 SharedPreferences AppPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
      boolean propertyManagerLoggedIn = AppPreferences.getBoolean(PROPERTYMANAGER_LOGGEDIN, false);

      if(!propertyManagerLoggedIn)
      {
         SharedPreferences.Editor editor = AppPreferences.edit();
         transitionInterface.showDashboardIcons();
         AppPreferences.edit().putBoolean("PROPERTYMANAGER_LOGGEDIN", true);
         editor.commit();
         //boolean vlaue = prefs.getbooleanflag(context, false);
         Log.d("tag",""+propertyManagerLoggedIn);

      }
     else
      {

         Log.d("tag",""+propertyManagerLoggedIn);
      }
```

and below is the relevant lines of code from  my AppPreferences class

```
 public final static String PROPERTYMANAGER_LOGGEDIN = "PROPERTYMANAGER_LOGGEDIN";

  public static boolean propertyManagerLoggedn(Context context)
   {
      TinyDB settings = new TinyDB(context);
      return settings.getBoolean(AppPreferences.PROPERTYMANAGER_LOGGEDIN);
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

every time you call `edit()` a new `Editor` is being returned to you. Accordingly to the documentation

> Create a new Editor for these preferences, through which you can make
>   modifications to the data in the preferences and atomically commit
>   those changes back to the SharedPreferences object.

so you can either do

```
AppPreferences.edit().putBoolean("PROPERTYMANAGER_LOGGEDIN", true).commit();
```

or

```
 editor.putBoolean("PROPERTYMANAGER_LOGGEDIN", true);
 editor.commit();
```

but calling `putBoolean` on an instance and `commit` on an other won't probably help

Answer (score 0):

You are calling commit on a different instance.
Basically `AppPreferences.edit()` will give you a new instance.

```
AppPreferences.edit().putBoolean("PROPERTYMANAGER_LOGGEDIN", true);
```

This is another instance in which you are putting the boolean value.

Use the same instance which you have created.
Your code should look like this:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = AppPreferences.edit();
         transitionInterface.showDashboardIcons();
         editor.putBoolean("PROPERTYMANAGER_LOGGEDIN", true);
         editor.commit();
```

Comment: Thank you let me try that. I also suspect that the way I am declaring it in app preferences is wrong . What is the correct way to declare it so I can then access it